FastAPI POST 422 Unprocessable Entity error
This is my FastAPI script, I am doing basic lesson to make the POST API as simple as possible.
class Item(BaseModel):
    test_param:str

@app.post('/myapi')
async def myapi(item:Item):
    print(item)
    return {"myapi":"OK"}

Then my script is like this:
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test_param',"1");
    axios.post("/myapi",formData
    ,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'}}).then(res=>{
console.log(res);
});

When calling API, it shows the error 422 Unprocessable Entity.
I guess there is some discrepancy in API and script, however where should I fix?

I updated the script ,for not using Model thanks to @M.O.
from typing import Annotated

@app.post('/myapi')
async def get myapi(test_param:Annotated[str,Form(default="test")]):
    print(test_param)
    return {"myapi":"OK"}

however this shows the error FastAPI POST 422 Unprocessable Entity
and this error, it says there is no field, but i have test_param in Form data 

The response payload likely has more inforation; give a [mre]. Maybe don't invent your own media types.

AFAIK, application/form-data is a standard media type, and FastAPI seems to default to it. The issue seems to be that, on the server side, fast_param wasn't declared.

I found the additional error message , it says.
{loc: Array(1), msg: 'value is not a valid dict', type: 'type_error.dict'}

You might find this and this helpful as well.

Have a look at this answer, if you would like to use a Pydantic model to define Form parameters.
